# Flutter Navigator - How to pass DocumentSnapshot<List> to Detail Page?

Tags: list, flutter, snapshot, navigator, pass-data

I'm searching for a solution to pass my snapshot via Navigator or others to my Detail Page.

```
   class SoccerList extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final database = Provider.of<FirestoreDatabase>(context, listen: false);
   return StreamBuilder<List<Soccer>>(
     stream: database.soccerStream(),
     builder: (_, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
         final soccer = snapshot.data;
         if (soccer == null) {
           return Scaffold(
             body: Center(
               child: Text('User list is empty',
                   style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
             ),
           );
         }
         return ListView.builder(
           itemCount: soccer.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             final item = soccer[index];

             return Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 5),
               width: double.infinity,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                 color: Colors.white,
                 boxShadow: [
                   BoxShadow(
                     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), //color of shadow
                     spreadRadius: 5, //spread radius
                     blurRadius: 7, // blur radius
                     offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                     //first paramerter of offset is left-right
                     //second parameter is top to down
                   ),
                   //you can set more BoxShadow() here
                 ],
               ),
               child: ListTile(
                 onTap: () {
                   Navigator.push(
                       context,
                       MaterialPageRoute(
                         builder: (context) => DetailBetScreen(soccer: soccer)
                           //[index],
                         )
                       );
                     
                 },
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                 ),
                 leading: IconButton(
                   iconSize: 24,
                   icon: new SvgPicture.asset('assets/ball/fussball7.svg'), onPressed: () {  },
                 ),
                   
                 
             
                 title: item.displayname != null? Text(item.displayname) : Text(item.sporttype),
                 subtitle: Text(item.sporttype),
               ),
             );
           },
         );
       }
```

The error message is:

Exception caught by widgets library:
type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot'
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp

How do i pass this snapshot (soccer) to a Detail Page? Sure the snapshot contains a List....i need both. Thnaks in advance for any idea!

This is my Stream:

```
Stream<List<Soccer>> soccerStream() => _service.soccerStream<Soccer>(
        path: FirestorePath.bets(),
        builder: (data, documentId) => Soccer.fromMap(data, documentId),
      );
```

And this is my Detail Screen:

```
class DetailBetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot soccerBet;
  DetailBetScreen({Key key, @required this.soccerBet}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class DetailBetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final dynamic soccerBet;
DetailBetScreen({Key key, @required this.soccerBet}) : super(key: key);
```